# Multiple Android projects using Crashlytics in the same Eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have installed Fabric (Crashlytics) plugin for Eclipse, set up single project to use Crashlytics. 4 dependency projects were created under that project, they got imported to the workspace, everything worked fine.

I wanted to set up second project, which is in the same workspace, to use Crashlytics. Did the Crashlytics initialization via the plugin, and got the same 4 Fabric dependency projects imported into workspace, just with "_2" appended to the name, see the image below.

[image]

If I close the auto-generated projects, I get build errors.

My questions:

1. How can I have multiple projects using Crashlytics in the same eclipse workspace? Is it possible to have Crashlytics in a project without importing those 4 generated projects to workspace?
2. Does there exist a standalone Crashlytics SDK, which could be installed without eclipse (or another IDE) plugin? This way I could add the same Crashlytics library projects to the multiple android projects.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround that I have found is to save Fabric (Crashlytics) generated projects to some location and delete the auto imported ones.

In your Fabric enabled project you will have "kits.properties" file. You can comment out the last line, which specifies the crashlytics version. This will prevent that project from re-generating and importing fabric libraries to your workspace. The file should look something like this:

```
# This file describes the kits for your project.
# Commit this and the kits folder into source control.
#com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2
```

After that, you can import previously saved projects to the workspace and add them as dependencies to your android project. You can add them to multiple projects, this solves the multiple auto generated projects problem.

Comment: The solution proposed by Crashlytics team was to use IntelliJ or Android Studio, also they suggested start using Gradle. Did not investigate this further yet since I have already found a solution described in the answer above.